# Python saving and replacing (help)

Tags: python

Im trying to do something, but i failed, and failed.
So i will try to explain you with examples:

If i make a list like and inputs:

```
addSomething = input("Enter something to add in the list: ")
myList = [addSomething]
```

And run this, how can a list like this be replaced and saved in the code.
I tried but even when I input something, code stays how it was and no replacing, and no new values.
How can this be replaced and saved? Hope you will understand.
I tried with `replace()` but it doesnt work.

Edited check this:

```
addSomething = input("Enter something to add in the list: ")
myList = []
myList.append(addSomething)
```

When i open the cmd(for windows) and run this python file, i will enter some thing in input, and i want for this input that i wrote, to be added in python file.

For example:

my input is: Hello, now the python file to be rewritten and to add the Hello string in myList.

Comment: By saved, do mean written to a file? Or to a variable in your script?

Comment: by saved, to written the python file and the list or variable to change its value or data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, every one who should do this, first:

```
open("filename.anyformatyoulike", "w")
```

second change the mode:

```
open("filename.anyformatyoulike", "a")
```

or use r+ , thanks guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = []
addSomething = input('Enter something to add in the list:')
#> val

#add it to the list
myList.append(addSomething)

#remove it by value
myList.remove('val')

#remove it by index
del myList[0]

#replace it by value
myList[myList.index('val')] = 'new val'

#replace it by index
myList[0] = 'new val'
```

Something like this?

```
addSomething = input("Enter something to add in the list: ")
#> user input
myList = [addSomething]
print(myList)
#['user input']
myList[0] = 'overwritten'
print(myList)
#['overwritten']
```

Comment: Yeah dude, this works but i want for this output(print) to be written in the python file after i input something, for ex: even i close the running program, i need these inputs to be saved in file.